# Елки будут или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

Шапки какие-то, лучше бы елки раздавали с игрушками) 
Или все-таки может быть будут и елки?

Comment: нет, елок  не будет.

Comment: @Grundy, жаль (

Comment: Елки с 22 декабря в кино :)

Comment: Есть надежда, что будет секретная шапка в виде ёлки.

Comment: Судя по видео, в 15-ом году елки таки были

Comment: Нет, видимо ёлок не будет, так как таковых нет в [списке на 2019 год](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list).